# How do I place a JSON file in a project?

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core

My ASP.NET Core program requires some data from a REST server, but during development, I do not need real data so I want to just use a JSON file as data like:

`program.cs`

```
  DataClass data = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<DataClass>(File.ReadAllText(<path_to_json_file>));
```

`mockData.json`

```
{
  "foo": "bar",
  ...
}
```

Where do I place the `mockData.json` and how do I write the path to the JSON file in `program.cs`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can place it anywhere in your project. Example:

[image]

In this case the path will be: `<FileName>`. So in code:

```
using (var sr = new StreamWriter("MyFileName.json")){ ... }
```

But for a json file to be readible you will need to change the properties. Right click on the file and ensure it is being loaded as content and being re-loaded when there is a newer file.

[image]

And that's it. No special instructions.

Comment: If I put it in a folder I just add the folder to the path right? e. g. `"folder\data.json"`